# Destructuring data from a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have an array of nested objects, like so:

```
const objArr = [{obj, obj, objIWant}, {obj, obj, objIWant}, {obj, obj, objIWant}]
```

Is there a way to get to `objIWant` without having to loop twice like:

```
ObjArr.map((obj)=> obj.map(({ objIWant }) => myFunc(objIWant)))
```

I was hoping I could perhaps leverage destructuring but trying something like `[{ objIWant }] = objArr` only returns the first `objIWant`. Am I missing something about destructuring syntax that would allow for this? Many thanks!

Comment: Is `{obj, obj, objIWant}` an array or an object?

Comment: It is a nested object, so `{"obj": {objectStuff}, "obj": { objectStuff } , "objIWant": { objIwant stuff }}` may be more accurate.

Comment: @fsp712 show your *actual* data. don't make people guess or make assumptions. it's a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: Try posting code that is at least not syntactically invalid. `const objArr = [{obj, obj, objIWant}, {obj, obj, objIWant}, {obj, obj, objIWant}]` fails.

Answer (score 1):

No - the only way to do it is with nested `map` calls.

```
ObjArr.map(obj => obj.map(({ objIWant }) => myFunc(objIWant));
```

If you are able to do so, you could change `myFunc`:

```
myFunc({ objIWant }) {...}
```

And then change your code to do this:

```
ObjArr.map(obj => obj.map(myFunc));
```

But there's no way using destructuring to do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring will not make it look cleaner. This is the only way to destructure the properties you want. Using the `map` function as you are now is a cleaner way of doing it.

```
const objArr = [{obj:1, obj2:2, objIWant:3}, {obj:4, obj2:5, objIWant:6}, {obj:7, obj2:8, objIWant:9}];
const [{objIWant}, {objIWant:test2}, {objIWant:test3}] = objArr;

window.console.log(objIWant);
window.console.log(test2);
window.console.log(test3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your structure is expected to return an array of objects - or an array of values from each object. But the solution would be the same - use .map() on the original array to return the values (or objects) that you want.

```js
const objArr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'first item', value: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'second item', value: 2},
  {id: 3, name: 'third item', value: 3}
];

const objIWant = 'value';
const result = objArr.map(item => item[objIWant]);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["1", "2", "3"]
```

if its a nested object then same deal - use .map() on the original array to construct a new array of the desired objects.

```js
  const objArr = [
    {"obj": {id: 1}, "obj": { id:1 } , "objIWant": { id:1 }},
    {"obj": {id: 1}, "obj": { id:1 } , "objIWant": { id:2 }},
    {"obj": {id: 1}, "obj": { id:1 } , "objIWant": { id:3 }}
  ];

    const objIWant = 'objIWant';
    const result = objArr.map(item => item[objIWant]);

    console.log(result);
    // expected output: Array [{"id": 1},{"id": 2},{"id": 3}]
```